# Summernote, set editor width and height

Tags: summernote

I can't seem to be able to set the editor to have a fixed width and height.
My code is

```
$('#myEditor').summernote({
    height: 20,
    width: 320,
    disableResizeEditor: true,
    airMode: true,
    popover: {
        air: [
            // [groupName, [list of button]]
            ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
            ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
            ['insert', ['link']]
        ],
        link: [
            ['link', ['linkDialogShow', 'unlink']]
        ]
    },
    callbacks: {
        onEnter: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        },
        onPaste: function (e) {
            var bufferText = ((e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('Text');
            e.preventDefault();
            document.execCommand('insertText', false, bufferText.replace(/\n/g, ''));
        }
    }
});
```

The editor width is not set using the config above.
Note that I am also using Bootstrap, if that makes a difference (I saw some issues about this). As soon as I type more text the editor grows. Basically I would like the field to behave like an input text field.
Is there a way to set the width and height in the config?
Do I have to try to set the DOM properties myself?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert  inside them

```
<textarea id="summernote">
    Place <em>some</em> <u>text</u> <strong>here</strong>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
</textarea>
```